# Limit WP_get_archives by category?

Tags: wp-get-archives

I have two categories on a site - news which contains news posts and blog - which contains blog posts. Each page has a wp_get_archives in the sidebar. I'd like to limit the archive listing by category but after looking at the codex this does not seem possible.  http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives

```
<?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly&limit=12'); ?>
```

That code lists the archives for all the posts, but I want to list archives for just that category. Am I using the wrong function? Or is this not possible?

Comment: Use this http://kwebble.com/blog/2007_08_15/archives_for_a_category

Answer (score 2):

Basically this is possible, but somewhat messy. This function relies on direct SQL query to database, which you can change via `getarchives_where` and `getarchives_join` filters.

Comment: but just for one category... what about if I want to separate the archive in three completely archives. One for blog, one for news and one for exhibitions. I have been able to take part of the URL so I fixed the next label. The problem is that the links of the archive widget always take me to the general archive with links like `mysite.com/2012/12` instead of `mysite.com/news/2012/12`

Comment: @toto_tico please ask new question about your issue :)

Comment: I did [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/104270/how-to-have-multiple-archives-widgets-one-archive-widget-per-category-in-a-dif). I finally found an answer that is sort of working. At least, I know I can tweak what is missing.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed this plugin and it seems to work fine.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-category-archive/installation/

Answer (score 0):

I use this code on my site to pull from a specific category (this is in the sidebar - shows just my 'blog' posts and not my 'portfolio' posts):

```
<ul>
<?php
global $post;
$myposts = get_posts('numberposts=10&category=3&order=DESC');
foreach($myposts as $post) :
?>
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could expand this and make it show only the posts for the category you're currently on by getting the category slug or ID from the post and passing into a variable. Then use the variable in your query for posts in the sidebar. Look at the $post global for taxonomy stuff or use get_term_by() to pull the whole term object then grab the slug or ID out of it with something like $var = $taxObject->slug; I'd put it in a counter so it only runs on the first post on the page.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not trying to display posts, I'm trying to display monthly archives like this http://nikibrown.com/uploads/a0fba9b8d23d24fdfcf76fb5d9eaaab7.png

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this workaround will do :
if instead of the archive you use RSS and specify for the RSS the number of post titles to be shown.

it is easy to get the RSS of the category - easy to specify nbre of posts.

no ? would it work ?