# How to have Multiple Archives Widgets, one archive widget per category (in a different page)?

Tags: categories, widgets, archives, custom-post-type-archives, wp-get-archives

Please read the whole question before assuming this question is repeated. After one day of trying plugins and tutorials, I am convinced that there is no straightforward method of achieving what I am trying.

Basically I am building a site that has different components: **Blog**, **News** and **Gallery**, they are all items in the menu. I am trying to have different archive widgets for all of them. So, when I go to **News** I can see my Archive Widget that just organizes information for **News**. The same for **Blog** or **Gallery**.

What have I tried?

1. **`get_archives`:** there is no category parameter for `get_archive`
2. **Categories**::

   2.1 **`getarchives_join` and `getarchives_where`** filters: They work well when is just one archive. Then you can modify the query one archive. **Problem**: I need more than one archive

   2.2 **adding templates, `template_include` filter and global variable**: this allowed me to have a global variable with the corresponding template name (`category-blog.php`, `category-news.php` and `category-archive.php`). With those names I could change the `getarchives_where` accordingly. **Problem**: This almost work until I realized that the widget links for the archive point to something like `mysite.com/2012/02` and use a different common template 'archive.php' (see 3 for using custom post type).

   2.3 **category in permalink and (`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`)**: this is more elegant than grabbing the permalink `mysite.com/2012/02` to something like `mysite.com/news/2012/02`. Then I can use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in the `getarchives_where`. **Problem**: I have no idea how to modify the `mysite.com/2012/02`. I research, `get_month_link` and `get_year_link`. There is no category parameter.
3. **Using custom post type**:: Obviously I needed `archive-news.php`, `archive-blog.php` and `archive-gallery.php` and add to my `getarchives_where` of 2.2. I crashed into `Custom Post Type`. I created and register the three custom post types: **Blog**, **News** and **Gallery**.

   3.1 **The `has_archive` delusion**: The parameter was there and I was convinced I got it. So I went to the news archive (`mysite.com/news`) and the archive was there. It worked on the right side displaying the news. **The problem**: The archive widget was still displaying the normal posts.

   3.2 **adding the archive templates to the `template_include` filter and global variable**: This is similar to 2.2 but with `archive-blog.php` and `archive-gallery.php`. **Problem**: Exactly the same as 2.2. The widget links for the archive point to something like `mysite.com/2012/02` and again using the the default common template 'archive.php' instead of the ones I created.
4. **Plugins**: I don't want to use a plugin for this but I did and didn't work.

   4.1. **jquery-archive-list-widget**: almost work except it works with exclude categories instead of include them. **Problem**: The link is still `mysite/2012/20/`. I am about to modify this plugin but I am still

   4.2. I tried a few others with less success.

How do I have different archive widgets according to category/post_type that appears according to the page I am?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an answer using Wordpress rewrites. The whole code is at the end and can be pasted in functions.php. There is just one parameter that you have to change `$rules = cpt_generate_date_archives('news', $wp_rewrite);` news is the name of the post_type. So I added a second line to show how to have two archives.

The code also includes the function `get_cpt_archives( 'news', true )` that prints (second parameter) a list (`<li>` based) to add as a sidebar.

```
/**
 * Custom post type date archives
 */

/**
 * Custom post type specific rewrite rules
 * @return wp_rewrite             Rewrite rules handled by Wordpress
 */
function cpt_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = cpt_generate_date_archives('news', $wp_rewrite);
    $rules = cpt_generate_date_archives('gallery', $wp_rewrite);
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
    return $wp_rewrite;
}
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'cpt_rewrite_rules');

/**
 * Generate date archive rewrite rules for a given custom post type
 * @param  string $cpt        slug of the custom post type
 * @return rules              returns a set of rewrite rules for Wordpress to handle
 */
function cpt_generate_date_archives($cpt, $wp_rewrite) {
    $rules = array();

    $post_type = get_post_type_object($cpt);
    $slug_archive = $post_type->has_archive;
    if ($slug_archive === false) return $rules;
    if ($slug_archive === true) {
        $slug_archive = $post_type->name;
    }

    $dates = array(
        array(
            'rule' => "([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})",
            'vars' => array('year', 'monthnum', 'day')),
        array(
            'rule' => "([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})",
            'vars' => array('year', 'monthnum')),
        array(
            'rule' => "([0-9]{4})",
            'vars' => array('year'))
        );

    foreach ($dates as $data) {
        $query = 'index.php?post_type='.$cpt;
        $rule = $slug_archive.'/'.$data['rule'];

        $i = 1;
        foreach ($data['vars'] as $var) {
            $query.= '&'.$var.'='.$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
            $i++;
        }

        $rules[$rule."/?$"] = $query;
        $rules[$rule."/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"] = $query."&feed=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
        $rules[$rule."/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$"] = $query."&feed=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
        $rules[$rule."/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$"] = $query."&paged=".$wp_rewrite->preg_index($i);
    }
    return $rules;
}

/**
 * Get a montlhy archive list for a custom post type
 * @param  string  $cpt  Slug of the custom post type
 * @param  boolean $echo Whether to echo the output
 * @return array         Return the output as an array to be parsed on the template level
 */
function get_cpt_archives( $cpt, $echo = false )
{
    global $wpdb; 
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = %s AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY YEAR(wp_posts.post_date), MONTH(wp_posts.post_date) ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC", $cpt);
    $results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

    if ( $results )
    {
        $archive = array();
        foreach ($results as $r)
        {
            $year = date('Y', strtotime( $r->post_date ) );
            $month = date('F', strtotime( $r->post_date ) );
            $month_num = date('m', strtotime( $r->post_date ) );
            $link = get_bloginfo('siteurl') . '/' . $cpt . '/' . $year . '/' . $month_num;
            $this_archive = array( 'month' => $month, 'year' => $year, 'link' => $link );
            array_push( $archive, $this_archive );
        }

        if( !$echo )
            return $archive;
        foreach( $archive as $a )
        {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $a['link'] . '">' . $a['month'] . ' ' . $a['year'] . '</a></li>';
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```